# Simplifying a pdf

Tags: probability

Given:
Uniform distribution.
$Y$ is a continuous random variable over $[0, 1]$, and $W=Y^2$.
I want to find the pdf for $W$.

Here's what I have: $F_W (w) = P(W\leq w)= P(Y^2\leq w)=P(Y\leq w^{1/2})=F_Y(w^{1/2})$.
Differentiating and using the chain rule gives the cdf $f_W(w)=f_Y(w^{1/2})/[2w^{1/2}]$.

How do I simplify this to $1/[2(w^{1/2})]$?  In other words, why is $f_Y(w^{1/2})=1$ for any $w \in [0, 1] $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what you wrote, there is no reason to think $f_Y(w^{1/2})= 1$.  That would be the case if it were given that $Y$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,1]$.  If not, then it might be true only of special values of $w$, or there might be no such values of $w$, and all of that would depend on what the distribution of $Y$ is.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the problem. I got it now, thank you!